How would I go about writing my own implementation of Win32 functions?
So I am currently coding a C program for Windows and come across a little bit of a problem. I've been compiling using the mingw-w64 toolchain. In my program, I am attempting to remove as many dependencies as I can. I've been using Dependency Walker to see which DLLs my program depends on. My question is how can I implement a function/functions from one of the DLLs my program depends on so that I can remove the dependency? I realize static linking is a thing but that would raise application size a lot for libraries that I only want to use one function from.
Example: I've written an example program that uses the GetUserNameW() function from the Windows API to retrieve, store, and eventually print the program runner's username. This function depends on the Advapi32 lib and Dependency Walker shows this dependency (Advapi32.dll). I want to be able to write my own GetUserNameW() function that behaves in the same way as the Win32 API function but allows me to remove the dependency on Advapi32.dll.

I removed the request for an open source project. Questions asking for resources, projects, or libraries is off-topic for this community. I like the example with GetUserNameW() though. At it's heart, this appears to be about managing dependencies in an application, which I think is on-topic. Perhaps a little more information about why removing dependencies on Win32 APIs is desirable will help attract answers.

It's not clear what you want to do. Is the question about how to implement your own version of a Windows API function? Is it about how to abstract away from a dependency on Windows so you can run on other OS's? Why do you want to remove these dependencies? That will help to decide how.

You're not coming anywhere near the User Registry with a custom-built user access function without every antivirus in the world nuking you into orbit. Using custom stuff for those things is unsafe, unwise, and shouldn't be done - please use the provided API's. They're standardized for a reason.

I would say it's more of a question about how to implement my own version of a Windows API function that I can eventually use and run on other OS's (although the running on other OS's bit isn't necessarily a requirement and more of just a learning tool). This was partially why I had a request about open-source implementations in my original question, because seeing that process in code would help my understanding. Let me know if any more info is needed, thanks <3

You very likely can't, without writing your own operating system. If you look at the disassembly of those functions, a lot of them are "set some values in some registers and then syscall and let the OS take care of the rest."

@TimC this is the explanation I was looking for, thank you. And thank you for being concise with it <3

@TimC, I do not understand your point. What prevents user code from setting up some registers and doing a syscall?

I will expand my comment into a proper answer then.

You cannot
Operating system APIs are implemented as part of the operating system. Most of them disassemble to "Set some values in some registers and then syscall and let the OS take care of the rest."
Can you do the same thing?
Conceivably, you could write your own home-grown assembly function that also sets some values in some registers and then syscalls, hooping that the OS will do what you want, but there would be no point in doing so. The functionality you would get is (at best) exactly identical to the OS's. There is no way that you can modify the behavior within the system call.
Additionally (on Windows), the system call table is not guaranteed to be stable. There is no guarantee that your manually crafted syscall will continue to work after the next time you update (though in practice, it does not change very much). Contrast to the public-facing entry points, which have stated (and often contractual/legal) commitments that they must continue to work.
What about if you're making your own OS?
Writing an OS is a substantial topic, too large for a single answer, but yes - if you were writing your own OS, you would need to implement the syscalls.
How do you actually write portable code?
If you want a GetUserName function that works across platforms, then you write an implementation for each platform you support, and a single entry point which routes to the appropriate platform specific code - that is to say, the entry point Windows API if on Windows, the Mac API if on Mac, the Linux API if on Linux, etc.

Why would @baron need to modify the syscall functionality? The goal is to exclude a DLL from dependencies, no new functionality needed, just replicate the old one. Why does the answer explain how to write for MacOS when the question is explicitly Windows only?
Stability guarantees are not a concern, as you write the code specific for every target anyway.

A sideways look at what you said about running on other OS: there is an implementation of almost all of the Windows API that runs on Linux, called WINE. You can see their implementation of these functions.
As for what the Microsoft implementation does .. a quick look in Ghidra reveals that it's extremely complicated. It doesn't just set up some registers and issue a syscall. It looks to me like it's issuing an RPC via some other APIs.
A full analysis of a similar function is available here.
But that's as expected. GetUserNameW is part of the Windows API. Microsoft reserve the right to change the implementation underneath you. You'll just have to accept that dependency. At least it's not a dependency you have to ship - you don't need to (musn't!) ship the ADVAPI32.DLL from your system, the user will already have one.

This is the best answer so far. +1

The guy looked at the code. Deserves +10.

From a technical perspective. Yes, you can do this. It can be accomplished by something called DLL search order hijacking. However this is a pretty rudimentary security vulnerability and is likely patched by most AVs. Alternatively you can simply just monkeypatch a particular (or a set of particular) function live and unload DLL once done (by performing an IAT hook and redirect it to your monkeypatched function). Both would require you to reverse engineer the implementation of said function, however.
From a pragmatic perspective, why would you ever do something like this? If your aim is to reduce the size of your binary, then I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news but this does exactly nothing because the DLL in question (winAPI DLLs) are in every windows OS. When you ship an executable that depends on a WinAPI DLL, you aren't shipping a copy of the DLL itself. The customer will be using their own version (which should be the same as yours, anyhow) of the WinAPI DLL. This kind of the reason why DLLs exist in the first place, anyways.
Addendum: Reading some of your comments, if your goal is to make your program portable across different OSes, then you are tackling a much bigger issue than simply polyfilling DLLs. For starters, not every OS (and I'm pretty sure most OSes do not) uses the DOS executable format. Your .exe doesn't run on Linux not because of the missing DLLs, but because Linux doesn't even recognise your .exe as a valid executable and have no idea how to run it. Consider using a managed language like Java or Python, they are kind of created for this exact purpose

IANAL
This is impossible in general. System libraries are specific for the OS distribution they come with and different distributions may have different implementations.
This impossible legally. Disassembly and reverse engineering are forbidden by EULA.
This is possible in practice - obtain a copy of the library from every target distribution, write a runtime dispatcher choosing a proper implementation depending on the environment.

"Disassembly and reverse engineering are forbidden by EULA" varies by jurisdiction, and the excellent free NSA reverse engineering tool Ghidra can help you with that.

If reverse engineering were illegal, all engineers (not just software engineers) would be out of a job and we'd still be living in caves. Thankfully that's not the case.
